# How to make multilevel cascading dropdownlist using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam new to jquery.But Im trying to search to make cascading multilevel dropdownlist using jquery or javascript.But Iam unable to find it.Please,help me find this.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you also put in what have you tried.

Comment: google->attempt a solution->IIF(Fail==true)?SO:"SUCCESS!"

Comment: try first with any concept you like, if you get stuck we are here to provide possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the tutorial where you can follow to create one yourself or just download it 
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/multi-level-dropdown-menu-css

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com), then you can leverage its [selectmenu widget](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/).

```
<select id="s1" name="s1"></select><br/>
<select id="s2" name="s2"></select><br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#s1').selectmenu({
        width: 250,
        change: function( event, element ) {
            if ($('#s1').val() != undefined) {
                $('#s2').html('');
                var options = $.get(); // populate options
                for(var opt in options)
                {
                    $target.append($('<option>', {
                        value: opt
                    }).text(options[opt]));
                }
                $('#s2').selectmenu('refresh').selectmenu('enable');
            } else {
                $('#s2').val('').selectmenu('disable');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```